# How to create a BEFORE UPDATE trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am having issues understanding triggers. I have to create a BEFORE UPDATE trigger which prevents an update to a table named Student if the
EnrolledDate is in the future. The table has an EnrolledDate column. I am aware that I would need an if statement, but I am not sure how to use it inside of the trigger and when to update the information. How would I compare the date from a table with a current date?

Comment: see Bill's comment in that dupe target up there

Comment: It is not a duplicate, since I am comparing date from a table with the current date.

Comment: it is a duplicate that shows how you forbid the trigger to perform. Thx.